# How to make IProgressMonitor wait for tasks to complete and then resume?

Tags: java, eclipse, eclipse-plugin

I'm using IProgressMonitor to display the status of the operations that I'm doing in an Eclipse plugin between a client and a server.

One of the operation is to authenticate to the server. For this I want to pop-up a preference page in case the fields in there are empty.

I want IProgressMonitor to wait for the user and when it is done to resume its main task.

Is it possible to achieve this using IProgressMonitor ?

Comment: Progress monitor does not have any sort of pause.

Comment: Can you recomend something else contained in Eclipse framework ?

Comment: Can't you start a sub-task from the monitor?

Comment: Yes, I can do that, but I don't know how to inform the monitor that it should  continue the task after I close the preference page...

Comment: Can't you work out that you need to show the page before you start the long running operation?

Comment: This is what I do...but I'm also using the monitor to display this to the user(I'm not doing this before starting the monitor): I say "Checking for credentials..." and if there are no credentials I display the page but then when pressing OK just want the IProgressMonitor to increment the bar and work normally